# How to add Hyperlink button in Messagebox in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, hyperlink, messagebox

I want to show hyper link in Messagebox. For example like this

[image]

If user clicks on location settings, it will open settings page. I want to do similar thing in may application too.

Thank you,
Naga Harish.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot customize the default MessageBox. Instead, you can create a cumstom User Control which you can use as a MessageBox.

Otherwise, I would suggest you use [MessagePrompt](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MessagePrompt), which helps you custimize it as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use the CustomMessageBox implementation from [the Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/)

Examples are found [here...](http://shawnoster.com/2012/10/welcome-custommessagebox-to-the-windows-phone-toolkit/) ( at the bottom with also a hyperlink like you are searching for )